# Flexslider nav buttons not visible on hover, with orange box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, flexslider

I'm using FlexSlider 2 on a WordPress site.

The back and forth nav buttons are not working--the back nav button is just an orange box and the forward nav button looks weird.

Check it out here: http://www.friendshipart.net/artists-acf/

CSS is here: http://www.friendshipart.net/wp-content/themes/colored-friendshipart/flexslider.css

Here is the script (in header.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        // Primary Controls
            directionNav: true,
            animation: "slide",
            controlsContainer: ".flex-nav-container",
    });
  });
</script>
```

How can I make the nav buttons appear normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the class `.flex-direction-nav li a` in the stylesheet style.css (which you linked to twice). Remove the height, width and text-indent from that class and add `padding:15px;`. Then in the stylesheet flexslider.css change the class `.flex-direction-nav a::before` to have `display:block;` instead of `display:inline-block;` and also in the same stylesheet, set `.flex-direction-nav a` width and height to 40px. But make sure you only keep one link to the stylesheet style.css because the styles will overwrite one another making it difficult to find problems in your css.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks Kinburn101 for your help. that fixed the issue, but the 'previous' arrow still isn't showing up. any thoughts? i may just disable the previous and next arrows if you're not sure how to fix it. i confirmed that the CSS is being linked to twice-- its because wp_head() is calling it twice and I'm not sure how to stop it from doing that. thank you!

Comment: was able to answer my question: I had to add text-align: right; to .flex-prev in flexslide.css. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sure that the reason that the previous arrow was not appearing with the initial changes is that style.css was being linked to twice. By you adding a new property that isn't being overwritten you are now able to see it. If I were you I would attempt to disable the second link somehow because it will lead to major issues if attempting to customize further.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'll see if I can disable the second link to the CSS